# Netlogo: to spread fear (change color and speed)

Tags: netlogo, panic

I have n-of turtles panic at the beginning of the simulation. `to panic` means to set `fear?` true, set color red and the speed is supposed to be 2 instad of 1. Those n-of turtles are supposed to spread their fear.
Now I have two problems:

- panicking turtles do not move faster than normal turtles

I tried `turtles-own [speed]` and `set speed speed + 2` for the panicking turtles (while fear? = true), but it doesn't work.

- panicking turtles won't spread their fear

I have the following code:

```
to panic
  set color red
  set speed speed + 2
  set fear? true
end

to fear
  ask n-of number-of-panicking-people turtles [panic]
end 

to spread
  ask turtles with [fear? = true and color != red]
  [ask other turtles-here with [fear? = false]
    [if (random-float 100) < spreadfear
      [panic]]]
end
```

The only thing that works so far is "to fear", where some turtles become red but the speed doesn't change etc.

Thank you!

Comment: That's better! At least, here, there is a bit of code to latch on to. Still, to diagnose why turtles with greater speed don't move faster, we'd need to see the part of the code where they actually move. I suppose you should have something like `fd speed` somewhere. Is that not the case? As for why the fear doesn't spread, your code looks alright to me. I suspect it might have something to do with `spreadfear`. Where is it defined? What is its value?

Comment: As an aside: you don't need to write `fear? = true` or `fear? = false`. It's already a boolean. Just write `fear?` or `not fear?`. E.g.: `ask turtles with [fear? and color != red]` and `ask other turtles-here with [not fear?]`.

Comment: spreadfear is a slider that goes from 0 to 100 with increment 0.1. It doesn't work regardless of the slider's value. I have not yet used speed in my code, but only fd 1, fd 0 and fd -1 in certain spots. What I did is to mention speed in the turtles-own, that's all. Is speed usually set on 1 so that it makes sense to say speed +2, or do I have to say all turtles have speed set on 1 before I can say set speed speed + 2?

Comment: I tried that (fear?), but it gave me an error message. But that's just a minor error that doesn't need to be fixed yet.

Comment: Regarding `fear?`: maybe it wasn't initialized? NetLogo variables are set to `0` by default, so somewhere in your setup code, when you create your turtles, you should make sure to have them `set fear? false`.

Comment: Regarding `speed`: you can't expect a variable to have an effect if you don't actually use it somewhere. NetLogo doesn't know that you want `speed` to represent the speed of turtles. Try replacing `fd 1` and `fd -1` with `fd speed` and `bk speed`, respectively.

Comment: Come to think of it: I bet the reason that fear doesn't spread is because your `fear?` variable is initially equal to `0`, so `turtles-here with [fear? = false]` is always empty.

Comment: Nicolas, that seems like the answer, maybe make it an answer instead of a comment?